# Debian/MIPS, how to boot from Qemu, how to get initrd?

Tags: debian

I have installed Debian/MIPS into Qemu VM. Everything went fine with `netboot/initrd.gz`. Unfortunately it does not boot now, because I have not installed any boot loader (or Debian installer have not installed it, I do not know). Where can I get the `initrd.gz` that the Debian installer has installed into the VM itself? Qemu will not start the VM without it.

Answer (score 3):

Well..I am not too sure but I believe one needs to have a BIOS ready in order to even run the QEMU executable for your target archiecture. Like in my case, I am using qemu-system-ppc.exe and I cannot boot it from the Debian CD for powerpc architecture. I must supply the boot ROM using the '-L' switch.

Perhaps this isn't what you are asking here. But if you are, this might perhaps help. By the way I cannot even get my system booted with Debian squeeze for PPC. Heres my question in case you find you know something that ive messed up: https://serverfault.com/q/447803/144654

Regards